# Как подключиться к github из visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, git, github

В Visual Studio уже встроен Git.
Везде пишут только как скачать уже имеющийся удалённый репозиторий с git hub'а, но нигде, как подключиться к гитхаб аккаунту из visual studio
Итак, у меня есть аккаунт на guthub, я создал приложение на локальном компе. Как мне через visual studio без доп плагинов подключиться к своему аккаунту, создать новый репозиторий и запушить папку с проектом в него?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847565/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-git-%D0%B2-visual-studio-2017 Вот тут пишут о смежной проблеме, возможно там есть новая для вас информация.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открыть Team Explorer (View - Team Explorer), затем кликните по иконке штепселя (Manage Connection):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более подробное описание в [документации](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/blob/master/docs/getting-started/authenticating-to-github.md)

PS Ещё в меню View - Other Windows есть пункт Github, но я им не пользовался, так как гитхабом не пользуюсь так как мне приходится чаще с tfs работать.

Answer (score 1):

Для GitLab и Githab, как подключиться из VS к удаленному аккаунту и добавить локальный проект в новый пустой репозиторий.

1) Сначала на gitlab.com создаем новый проект с названием, соответствующим локальному проекту. На Github так же, только Репозиторий.

2) В Visual Studio в проекте нажимаем внизу окна кнопку «Добавить в систему управления версиями»=> git. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) В разделе "Отправить в удаленный репозиторий" вводим URL-адрес созданного на сайте репозитория проекта, нажимаем Опубликовать. Проект должен загрузиться на сайт.